# Expected type 'Union[str, PathLike[str]]', got 'None' instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I want to parse an open-access dataset.

```
def parse():
    zipurl = 'xyz'
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(zipurl) as tfile:
    # Write the contents of the file into the temporary file
    tfile.write(zipurl.read())
    # Set the file's current position at the offset
    tfile.seek(0)
    # Unpack the archive file in the parent directory
    parent = Path(unpack_archive(tfile.name, '/tmp/dataset', format='zip')).parent)

    for file in parent.iterdir():
            if file.is_file():
                old_name = file.stem
                extension = file.suffix
                directory = file.parent
```

Error:
Expected type 'Union[str, PathLike[str]]', got 'None' instead

The error was raised at `parent = Path(unpack_archive(tfile.name, '/tmp/dataset', format='zip')).parent)`

My pycharm version is Edu 2021.1.1

Comment: what pycharm version do you have? at what line the warning is raised?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up between filepaths (which are strings) and file-objects (which are complex objects).

```py
import tempfile
from pathlib import Path

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp_file:
    print(f"type: {str(type(temp_file))}")
    print(f"name: {temp_file.name}")
    parent = Path(temp_file.name).parent
    print(f"parent: {str(parent)}")
    for file in parent.iterdir():
        print(f"sibling: {str(file)}")
```

prints for me :

```
type: <class 'tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper'>
name: C:\Users\LENORMJU\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpssxs7qwk
parent: C:\Users\LENORMJU\AppData\Local\Temp
sibling: C:\Users\LENORMJU\AppData\Local\Temp\07379b78-601f-4cf3-bc73-427d7254d49a.tmp.ico
sibling: C:\Users\LENORMJU\AppData\Local\Temp\0b5d3696-4fc7-4823-bacb-dc7988ef3190.tmp.ico
...
```

The error was `Expected type 'Union[str, PathLike[str]]', got 'IO[Union[Union[str, bytes], Any]]' instead` which means that `pathlib.Path` expected a string or a path-like, but what you gave it was a file object (called `IO[Union[str, bytes]]`).

Your error was giving a file-object instead of a string (the path to the file).

I think you should iterate over `Path('/tmp/dataset')`, which is where the zip gets extracted, instead of `Path(tfile)` (which is the zip content).

Comment: `with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(zipurl) as tfile:
        tfile.write(zipurl.read())
        tfile.seek(0)
        parent = Path(unpack_archive(tfile.name, '/tmp/dataset', format='zip')).parent
        for file in parent.iterdir():
            ........`

Error at the line before the loop:
Expected type 'Union[str, PathLike[str]]', got 'None' instead

Comment: `parent = Path(tfile.name).parent`

Comment: Will it unpack the file automatically? Or will I need to unpack after that?

Comment: do both : extract the zip into the `'/tmp/dataset'` directory then iterate over it with `for file in Path('/tmp/dataset').iterdir()`. Because you hardcoded the path where to extract the files, there is no need for a `parent here`. If you decide to not hardcode the extraction path anymore, then ask a new question.

Comment: If I choose not to hardcode, how do I work around it? Would you mind providing a sample solution based on my code above? I'm new to python. Thanks